# ¿How to retain scroll of TabLayout when adding new Tabs?

Tags: android, tabs, horizontal-scrolling

I have the next problem, when I add tabs manually with a button to TabLayout then the scroll move and the first tab is not visible to the user. I want to retain the position of scroll.

In the next code, I add tabs when I press a button.

```
private void addRandomTab() {

    Random r = new Random();

    String cheese = Cheeses.sCheeseStrings[r.nextInt(Cheeses.sCheeseStrings.length)];

    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(cheese));

    mPagerAdapter.addTab(cheese);
}
```

Thanks.
Greetings.